# pyspark agg select from pivot column only if column exists

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

trying to select column based on pivoted data. Sometime it doesn't exists in a specific environment. How can we handle the select column if it doesn't exists in the pyspark dataFrame ?

this is what I came up with, but running into an error

```
df = (
    df.groupby("col1", "col2")
    .pivot("col3")
    .agg(F.sum("col4"))
    .groupby("col1")
    .pivot("col2")
    .agg(
        F.first("ABC").alias("col5"),  # value in col3
        F.first("EFG").alias("col6"),  # value in col3
        F.when(
            df.columns.contains("XYZ"),
            F.first("XYZ"),
        )
        .otherwise(F.lit(None))
        .alias("col7"),  # value in col3. XYZ may or may not be a value in col3
    )
)
```

however, I am getting this error

```
'list' object has no attribute 'contains'
```

How you suggest we can achieve the required ?

Comment: so found out that we can define values with PIVOT, in case the value doesnt exists, PIVOT creates the value
.pivot("col3", ["ABC", "EFG", "XYZ"]) in case above